# Does session variable shared across different browser?

Tags: c#, asp.net, vb.net, visual-studio

Does session variable shared across different browser? If not is there away that I can share information across browser similar to the functionality of caching but the scope is wider.

Comment: What do you mean "across different browser"? Do you mean that user1 is using both IE and FireFox and you want to share the session between them?

Comment: Yes, that is what I mean but as suggested by others there is no way I can achieve this but to store the information server-side.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The session is specific to a user's session ID (generally stored in a cookie named `ASP.NET_SessionID`), which won't be the same across multiple browsers (unless [something is wrong](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Session_hijacking)).

To persist data across multiple browsers, you're going to have to store data on the server-side in some other format, likely a database. If data needs to be specific to certain individuals, you'll probably need to set up an authentication scheme to properly restrict the data to the appropriate users.

Comment: I read before that session variable stores it value in the server. Is there no way that I can retrieve this?

Comment: True, session data is stored on the server side, but it's not practical to retrieve the data through means other than the `Session` object. I'd look into persisting data in ASP.NET's cache or a database or something like that instead.

Answer (score 1):

It depends on what your session implementation is backed by. The default is that session is unique to one browser since it's identified by a session cookie issued by your browser. Only the browser session that issued the cookie can identify the session on the server.

There are other implementations that are not based on session cookies (url, sql server backed) which would allow you to share across browsers

Answer (score 1):

No. Session variables are tied to a session identifier which is only known by the browser instance which started the session (or in the more complicated case of recent IE releases, by the underlying engine, but it's still all IE).